# How to say "stirring spoon" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have tried ReVo, ESPDIC and Google Translate with no success. Maybe I am calling it wrong in English. It's an *ilo* that's suppossed to look like this:

[image]

I noted besides "stirring" it's also called a "wooden" or a "cooking spoon", all of which obviously can be given (mutually different) direct translations. But I'm not interested in, for example, a [image] that's just made of wood, if there's any more direct term. With what I mean I wouldn't eat a soup, rather make one: it's too shallow and large and has splinters!

It seems that German and French have some analogues of "cooking" and "wooden" spoon, respectively. Russian, to my best knowledge, has a separate word for this, based on stirring, and Polish "warzecha" is similarly a single word, based on cooking (no idea on how to parse "kopyść"). So there's no agreement between these languages either, at least not enough to pick one of the above options.

Comment: In English the distinction between a "wooden spoon" (as depicted) and a cereal spoon that happens to be made out of wood is entirely cultural, not linguistic. And "stirring spoon" isn't even cultural, it's more your local group. I thought you were talking about something for tea not stews. - I say this to note that the thing you're asking for may exist in esperanto but it does not exist in english so there would be no clean reverse translation if it did exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first impulse would be to call it a *ligna kulero* or *lignokulero*, but since there are places where people use wood (e.g. bamboo) for table cutlery, perhaps you might prefer *ligna kuirkulero, kirlkulero, mikskulero* (respectively: *cooking, stirring, mixing spoon*).

Comment: I think "kuirkulero" is great!

Comment: Hmm, so basically we are at square 0 with all the options (that are possible in English) back in the game :-) But I, too, think it can't get much better than *kuirkulero* or *mikskulero*. Thanks!

Comment: _mikskulero_ IMHO is preferable, because _kirli_ is much faster than mixing/stirring (which in E-o both are _miksi_), a _kirlilo_ is a swizzle stick.

Answer (score 2):

- Spoon made of wood = kulero el ligno
- Wooden spoon = ligna kulero

Comment: Ankaŭ la Bildvortaro (p. 111) nomas ĝin tiel.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see what the problem is, here we call them wooden spoons, why you can't do the same in Esperanto, we never eat with wooden spoons only metal and sometimes plastic.

Comment: The problem is that you're making assumptions from your own culture that might not hold in other places. In German this would be a _Kochloeffel_ ('cooking spoon'), whereas you can perfectly well eat with a wooden spoon (_Holzloeffel_). Otherwise Esperanto would just be English with direct one-to-one word translations.

Comment: i can confirm that despite being in the USA, I have wooden spoons (bamboo specifically) that conform to the traditional US table spoon sizes and I am capable of eating with them.